# Python how to get file plot graph sine wave?

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sr = 2000         
ts = 1 / sr       
file_name = 'C:/Users/Desktop/test_data/sample_003.csv'

def x_sine():
    sample = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    array = np.array(sample)
    where_are_NaNs = np.isnan(array)
    array[where_are_NaNs] = 0

    x = array[:, 1]
    y = array[:, 2]
    z = array[:, 3]
    t = np.arange(0, np.size(x)) * ts

    ax = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t * x / sr)

    f = plt.figure()
    plt.title('Sine Wave Test - x-axis' + '\n' + file_name.split('/')[-1])

    plt.plot(x, ax)
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude = sin(time)')

    plt.show()
```

sample_003.csv
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AcnR.png)
I want to get a file and draw a sine graph. But when I do this, the graph comes out weird. I don't know what to do. Help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.sin()` to plot sine wave.

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = np.arange(-5,5,0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The wave like that, and it can customized by you
[image]